# How to enable server-status on apache2?

Tags: raspbian, apache-httpd

I'm running a LAMP stack on Raspbian and I'd like to see the apache server-status page. I've checked that mod-status is enabled and I've added a directive in apache2.conf to allow anyone to see the page while I test it:

```
<Location /server-status>
    SetHandler server-status
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from all
</Location>
```

When I navigate to the page I'm still getting a 'forbidden' warning. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

Remove this line:

```
Deny from all
```

This should make the status page available to anyone.

When you want to restrict the IP addresses that can access the status page, put that line back. On the `Allow` line, replace `all` with the IP address of your PC/laptop.